# Can I pass composer my private pip repo credentials without having to store these secrets in a GCS bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-composer

I have my own publicly accessible (Artifactory cloud) pip repo I want to use with cloud composer. I have no networking requirements because it's public it just needs authentication.

I really don't want to have my Artifact repository's credentials sprinkled throughout a bunch of GCS buckets: https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/installing-python-dependencies#install-public-repo

Buckets can be locked down to some extent, but I would like to know if there is another way here.

Is there some way to just pass the `gcloud composer environments create|update` commands pip credentials directly? This is how it should work as it does with my other CI/CD pipelines where I dynamically fetch and generate pip.conf files per build and they are cleaned up automatically and not stored in insecure locations.

I could have a build pipeline that generates and uploads pip.conf, builds the environment, and then removes pip.conf from the bucket to clean up. Before I go down that road I want to check that's the only way.

I would expect composer to have an integration with Google Secrets Manager or something for this kind of thing. I'm surprised Google is telling me to store secret strings in a GCS bucket.

Comment: Do you use composer 1 or 2?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Composer 2 I believe, thats the latest and greatest right?

Comment: The Mazlum's answer is correct. But I still have another point of view. Why do you want to install specific libraries on Composer? To run your own code? You shouldn't!! The orchestrator is here to orchestrate thing, not to run things. If you do that, you will mix orchstration and business rules. You have to create containers and deploy them either on Composer or elsewhere and invoke them from the orchestrator. By the way the orchestrator stay simple, and your own dependencies are to add to the processing part (the containers). If you think separation of duty, it will be obvious!

Comment: Guillaume, I understand your point and you are right to indicate to put business rules outside of orchestration, but sometimes we can share treatments or libs for elements that concern only orchestration.

Comment: My question is about a specific, officially supported, feature of the platform not about DAG arch regardless. Answers should focus on my actual question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, unfortunately there is no other solution for public repositories.
You have to add access credentials in the extra repo URL in the `pip.conf` file.

Then copy this file in the `Composer` bucket.

You can think about a way to secure the access to this object in the bucket used by `Composer`.

Unfortunately there is the same constraint with `Composer 1` and `Composer 2`.

Comment: Would it cause problems if, as part of a build pipeline, I uploaded, created env, and then deleted the pip.conf from the bucket? It should only need that during env build and update operations right?

Comment: I think yes, the pypi packages and pip.conf file are used while creating/updating environnement and machines. You can try this but, you need to manage in your CI CD pipeline, the copy and deletion of pip.conf file from the bucket.

Comment: The pip.conf isn't embedded into the composer artifact container images after they are built right?

Comment: I think not, when we create the cluster for the first time, there is no the pip.conf file by default